# Activesheet vs Worksheet Object

Tags: vba, excel

In a worksheet tool which I am using, I have a linked table to a Sharepoint list.  A macro which I wrote refreshes the table and removes any filters if any are activated.

The issue which I had with this code was resolved via a quick code change, but I don't quite understand why the activesheet reference fixes the issue and would like to source some feedback from other developers experience with VBA.  Code is below:

**Code throws error: method of worksheet class failed**

```
  Dim ResourceTableSheet As Worksheet

  Set ResourceTableSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ResourceTableSheet")
  If (ResourceTableSheet.AutoFilterMode And ResourceTableSheet.FilterMode) Or ResourceTableSheet.FilterMode Then
            ResourceTableSheet.ShowAllData  <-- **method of worksheet class failed error here**
  End If
```

**Resolution - Working Code**

```
  Dim ResourceTableSheet As Worksheet
  Set ResourceTableSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ResourceTableSheet")

  ResourceTableSheet.Activate
  If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
            ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
   End If
```

Comment: Did you try adding `ResourceTable.Activate` to your original code (and not changing anything else) ?

Comment: Updated the code, I didn't activate teh sheet per say but I did declare it as an object

Comment: I can't replicate your problem

Comment: In the second code, after the line `ResourceTableSheet.Activate`, type this `Msgbox ActiveSheet.Name` And now run the code. What do you get?

Comment: It seems to be something to do with the thisworkbook reference, if I set that variable to a workbook object (Set wb1 = ThisWorkBook) and then  use Set ResourceTableSheet = wb1.Worksheets("ResourceTableSheet"), it runs fine.  If I use  Set ResourceTableSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ResourceTableSheet") it throws an error

Comment: Now this is a new one :) I am sorry, I can't think of anything to suggest

Comment: Any chance, we can have a look at the workbook

Comment: Time to learn how to debut in VBA.

Comment: Weird. Your first code works fine for me. No error. Not even when the filter is only encompassing part of the rows. Not even on hiden sheet!

What version of Excel are we talking about here?

Comment: I have linked a sharepoint list to "ResourceTableSheet" worksheet - the first code without .Activate still works just fine. You say "refreshes the table and removes any filters" - how and where exactly do you refresh? In that if / end if block? Sure the problem does not lie within the refresh?

Comment: the refresh is a separate line of code which happens after disabling the autofilter.  Thisworkbook.Connections("owssvr").Refresh

The version is Excel 2013, and do not forget that the table is linked to a sharepoint data source, I have never had this problem until I worked with a linked table

Comment: Wait, wait.   
    Thisworkbook.Connections("owssvr").Refresh    
How exactly have you linked that SP list? The way I did it, my refresh looks like this:  
    ResourceTableSheet.QueryTables(1).Refresh     
Do you create the Worksheet somehow *on the fly* ? Sorry for asking perhaps stupid questions, I am not terribly experienced with linked SP sheets.

Comment: If you export any list in sharepoint to an excel file, it will automatically generate a connection back to the sharepoint server.  I took the connection name and refreshed it via the connection name rather than referencing the table itself and initiating a refresh command.  Your way also works and its probably better practice :)

Comment: I see. Still cannot reproduce though. I now exported a SP list to Excel (2010), added a module, inserted your code and bam it worked. Inserted  ThisWorkbook.Connections("owssvr").Refresh before the if block and it still worked. :-??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of danced around in the comments, but in my experience there are certain things that don't work unless the object (worksheet, chart, etc) is the active/selected object. I don't have a definitive list, but I've experienced the same sort of issue in the past and resolved it the way you did (making the object active).

I've also never been able to find out why it was that way. I spent some time looking, but ultimately just wrote it off as Microsoft being Microsoft and moved on.

Comment: You'd be right, I found something in another thread which stated that activating the sheet is essential before setting the worksheet variable and initiating commands from that variable.  I personally think its a hiccup in the VB6 syntax